# upload file (gpx) with curl

Tags: curl

I'm tyring to upload a file in a URL (http://www.endomondo.com) but I can't. I can login in the url but I can't upload the file. Could you help me please? Many thanks and sorry for my english. My code is:

```
curl -Lc trackcookie.txt http://www.endomondo.com
curl -Lb trackcookie.txt -d 'email=example@gmail.com&password=PASSWORD' 'https://www.endomondo.com/access?wicket:interface=:1:pageContainer:lowerMain:lowerMainContent:signInPanel:signInForm::IFormSubmitListener::'
curl -v  -F filedata=pistaSubir.gpx 'http://www.endomondo.com/?wicket:interface=:4:importPanel:wizardStepPanel:uploadForm:uploadSumbit::IActivePageBehaviorListener:0:-1&wicket:ignoreIfNotActive=true&wicket:ajax=true' 
* About to connect() to www.endomondo.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 176.34.249.204... connected
* Connected to www.endomondo.com (176.34.249.204) port 80 (#0)
> POST /?wicket:interface=:4:importPanel:wizardStepPanel:uploadForm:uploadSumbit::IActivePageBehaviorListener:0:-1&wicket:ignoreIfNotActive=true&wicket:ajax=true HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (i486-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.15
> Host: www.endomondo.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 157
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------7b8c4aecfb15
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Ajax-Location: login
< Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
< Content-Type: text/xml
< Date: Mon, 28 Nov 2011 16:25:34 GMT
< Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
< P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"
< Pragma: no-cache
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=5760211D1D4B635A02E9D69677DA8B73; Path=/
< Set-Cookie: AWSELB=596D5F61100CE5ABA8843B846DBDD12FB4223A2CC68ACE6074E3879F3B06AB55F6DA7DE246A1B11DF015B7EDB45CF82FE78510C4A5506ED5E5BDAC87E60C799B569AEC08B252AE864ABBF774F8FF8209C889D10CCA;PATH=/
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=9
< Content-Length: 69
< Connection: keep-alive
```

EDIT
The Live HTTP Headers:

```
http://www.endomondo.com/?wicket:interface=:2:importPanel:wizardStepPanel:uploadForm:uploadSumbit::IActivePageBehaviorListener:0:-1&wicket:ignoreIfNotActive=true&wicket:ajax=true

POST /?wicket:interface=:2:importPanel:wizardStepPanel:uploadForm:uploadSumbit::IActivePageBehaviorListener:0:-1&wicket:ignoreIfNotActive=true&wicket:ajax=true HTTP/1.1
Host: www.endomondo.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; es-ES; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100423 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.3
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: es-es,es;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://www.endomondo.com/?wicket:interface=:2::::
Cookie: __utma=162144232.314244061.1322224370.1322495708.1322558556.5; __utmz=162144232.1322224370.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); EndomondoApplication_USER=username%40gmail.com; EndomondoApplication_AUTH=gy49RxPy-Y*w8HJnWKXN90BPgWw; JSESSIONID=290127FBBDF7991EE5F8A4EEBE01292E; AWSELB=596D5F61100CE5ABA8843B846DBDD12FB4223A2CC65233E77DF36EB7F1D876257A06A22E14AD397261D99E802164D454611D470D0F989FFAF7A29F03F689F08EA8B56FBD2C05FBE9A6DA21746C8543605F8C9E21C7; __utmb=162144232.3.10.1322558556; __utmc=162144232
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------75208478120228366171295351650
Content-Length: 54514
-----------------------------75208478120228366171295351650
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="idb0_hf_0"


-----------------------------75208478120228366171295351650
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadFile"; filename="pistaSubir.gpx"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx creator="http://sportstracklive.com" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:gpxtpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd"><metadata><link lon="-3.644933701"><ele>715</ele><cadence>76</cadence><extensions><gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension><gpxtpx:hr>175</gpxtpx:hr></gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension></extensions><time>2011-11-23T18:26:51Z</time></trkpt></trkseg></trk></gpx>
-----------------------------75208478120228366171295351650
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadSumbit"

1
-----------------------------75208478120228366171295351650--

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 29 Nov 2011 09:23:27 GMT
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-UA-Compatible: IE=9
Content-Length: 4240
Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 0):

The third `curl` doesn't use the cookies file.

Comment: If I do: curl -v -Lb trackcookie.txt -F filedata=pistaSubir.gpx 'http://www.endomondo.com/?wicket:interface=:4:importPanel:wizardStepPanel:uploadForm:uploadSumbit::IActivePageBehaviorListener:0:-1&wicket:ignoreIfNotActive=true&wicket:ajax=true'. Doesn' works

Comment: @flesk: Do you know hot could I do it? Thanks

Comment: Show http dump then. Also, you could do the request via browser and use a tool to display a http traffic, then compare it to the curl's one.

Comment: I'm using LIve HTTP Headers. I cant find the difference:

Comment: With Live HTTP headers: http://www.endomondo.com/?wicket:interface=:2:importPanel:wizardStepPanel:uploadForm:uploadSumbit::IActivePageBehaviorListener:0:-1&wicket:ignoreIfNotActive=true&wicket:ajax=true

With Curl: http://www.endomondo.com/?wicket:interface=:2:importPanel:wizardStepPanel:uploadForm:uploadSumbit::IActivePageBehaviorListener:0:-1&wicket:ignoreIfNotActive=true&wicket:ajax=true

Comment: Your dump in the question doesn't have cookies. Could you update the question and include the headers you have?

Comment: The server responses back with `Content-Length: 4240`. What is it? Maybe an error is displayed? Also, could you show a browser's request/response dumps to compare?

Comment: I don't know. I've copied from LIve HTTP headers of firefox.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking? Live HTTP headers and cur's headers are very different. It doesn't have cookies, form fields are completely different (e.g. where is a `idb0_hf_0`, `uploadFile`, `uploadSubmit`??). Also if you want to send file contents, use `@` before file name in curl command line (as in manual). Just carefully check all mismatches and do exactly the same.